# SAP HANA SQL Query with Dynamic Placeholder

Tags: hana

I have a query that is passing the current year as a placeholder parameter that right now is hard coded. How can I have this just pass the current year? I've seen a few different potential solutions but most of them are in HANA Studio or involve dynamic SQL generation.

I'm putting the SQL into Tableau so those are both off the table.

```
...sum("StockInQualityInspection") as in_quality,
         sum("StockInTransit") as its
  from "_SYS_BIC"."stream.models.marketing.poly/InventoryQuery" ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IPCurrentYear$$', '2018'))
  where "StockValuatedUnrestrictedUse" <> 0 or "StockInQualityInspection" <> 0 or "StockInTransit" <> 0
  group by case when "ReceivingPlant" is null then "Plant" else "ReceivingPlant" end, 
           case....
```

Comment: `Select year(now()) from dummy`  so just `year(now())`  careful around edge cases such as time zone variances at year end/year beginning..

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the parameters input of your CV
- Add this expression: year(now())

If you don't have access to manipulate the CV, into your query use:

- ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IPCurrentYear$$', select year(now()) from DUMMY))

Regards

Answer (score 0):

while placing a query is not permitted, you can pass a parameter as following

```
 do begin
  declare lv_param nvarchar(100);
  select max('some_date')
    into lv_param
  from dummy /*your_table*/;
  
  select *
  from "_SYS_BIC"."path.to.your.view/CV_TEST" (
    PLACEHOLDER."$$P_DUMMY$$" => :lv_param
  );
end;
```

more can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65305725/can-i-place-a-sql-query-in-a-sql-hana-place-holder)
credit to [@astentx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2778710/astentx)