# How to escape sql injection from HANA placeholder

Tags: php, odbc, sql-injection, hana

I have some HANA queries which use `PLACEHOLDER` input and of course I want to prevent an sql injection.

I try to use `?` in `odbc_prepare()`

```
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT
    col,
    ...
FROM table_name('PLACEHOLDER'=('$$some_key$$', ?))
WHERE col = ?
SQL;
$stmt = \odbc_prepare($conn, $query);

if ($stmt !== false) {
    \odbc_execute($stmt, ['placeholder_value', 'where_value']);
}
```

but I receive this warning:

```sh
Warning: odbc_prepare(): SQL error: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near &quot;?&quot;: line 32 col 40 (at pos 1283), SQL state 37000 in SQLPrepare
```

and statement wasn't created. So my code now looks like this:

```
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT
    col,
    ...
FROM table_name('PLACEHOLDER'=('$$some_key$$', 'placeholder_value'))
WHERE col = ?
SQL;
$stmt = \odbc_prepare($conn, $query);

if ($stmt !== false) {
    \odbc_execute($stmt, ['where_value']);
}
```

As I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22117157/6090395) `htmlspecialchars()` is not enough to prevent an SQL injection.

I can't [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52208244/6090395) input placeholder, I don't own HANA.

Is there any other way to prevent SQL injection in `PLACEHOLDER`?

Comment: There's not enough here to diagnose your issue... How are you sending the parameters? Can we see the full query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (old) placeholder syntax `('PLACEHOLDER'=('<varname>', '<var value>'))` you're using here does not allow for bind variables.

Instead, the new placeholder syntax `(PLACEHOLDER."<varname>"=>?)` allows using bind variables.

In your code this would look like this:

```
$query = <<<SQL
SELECT
    col,
    ...
FROM table_name (PLACEHOLDER."$$some_key$$" => ?)
WHERE col = ?
SQL;
$stmt = \odbc_prepare($conn, $query);
```