# Using HANA PLACEHOLDER query from java with named parameter replacement

Tags: java, spring-boot, hana

Could someone please explain to me , the difference between using a `PLACEHOLDER` and a `WHERE` in sap hana queries. I am new to SAP HANA and in my springboot application , I have to use one PLACEHOLDER query to get some data from a calculated view. The issue is that when using spring data jpa along with SAP HANA , for some reason the PLACEHOLDER query fails to replace the values dynamically during query creation. For instance take the query :

```
select * from SOME_TABLE ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_SOME_COLUMN1$$', 'value1') ,('$$IP_SOME_COLUMN2$$', 'value2'));
```

whenever we try to dynamically pass values to this query , for some reason the query creation fails . So, we were hoping to use the all so familiar `WHERE` clause instead , but need clarification on the difference between them and how it might affect performance.

Comment: how do you call your query with JPA? Give the code of your dynamics. Did it work before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the `WHERE`-clause placeholders in HANA are a non-standard/proprietary syntax extension.
The idea is that a query can provide additional information to a view - often that would be filter conditions that otherwise would not be possible to "push-down" in the processing.

These concepts overlap in their use-cases but are completely distinct in their implementation and meaning otherwise.

Concerning the "passing values dynamically" question: the old placeholder syntax does not support SQL query parameters/host variable replacement (the ? in the query text).
To do that, you need to use the new variant of the parameter syntax.

See also [How to escape sql injection from HANA placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483948/how-to-escape-sql-injection-from-hana-placeholder).

Comment: Could you please provide one sample query using the new parameter syntax for PLACEHOLDER query ?

Comment: Yes but out HANA version is ancient (v1.0) , is that going to cause any issues if we use the newer syntax in our java application ?

Comment: Also the current syntax allows us to pass multiple values to each placeholder keys, is that behavior going to be the same even if we use your updated syntax . It would be great if you could share some documentation as well , as I couldn't find much support online.

Comment: If your HANA system accepts the syntax then I wouldn’t expect problems here. How about you try it out first and see how it goes?

Comment: The syntax is discussed at several places in the documentation. One of them is ["SAP HANA Developer Guide - Input Parameters"](https://help.sap.com/viewer/52715f71adba4aaeb480d946c742d1f6/2.0.04/en-US/d5c8230abb571014acc592c2c96d92bd.html)

Comment: I tried executing the query like `select * from SOME_TABLE ((PLACEHOLDER."$$IP_SOME_COLUMN1$$", 'value1') ,(PLACEHOLDER."$$IP_SOME_COLUMN2$$", 'value2'));` directly in HANA server but it's throwing syntax error.

Comment: The syntax is `(PLACEHOLDER."<varname>" => '<value>' )` with that little `=>` in between.

Comment: It's working, thank you for your time and effort. `select * from SOME_TABLE (PLACEHOLDER."$$IP_SOME_COLUMN1$$" => 'value1' ,PLACEHOLDER."$$IP_SOME_COLUMN2$$" => 'value2');` worked for me.

Comment: how does this work when passing a * (for a place holder that i can put a list of strings or a * to select all) the => works for me when placeholders that accept a string, but im getting an error for placeholders that accept a list of strings or a star

Answer (score 0):

The function [APPLY_FILTER](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US/a09d584807f84477a64d7625ca45b089.html) applies a SQL predicate just like if it was added to the where clause.
In the example below the variable **sql_filter** contains a complex filtering predicate that we want to apply without using dynamic SQL. This is the list of all views created on a Friday:

```
do begin
  declare sql_filter nvarchar(200) = 'weekday(create_time)=4'; 
  tv= select dayname(create_time) as create_day, schema_name, view_name
  from VIEWS;
  res=APPLY_FILTER(:tv, :sql_filter);
  select * from :res;
end;
```

This construct with do begin and table variable is not that easy to call from a client application, so I recommend that you write a table function instead:

```
create or replace function DYN_FILTER_VIEWS(
    IN SQL_FILTER NVARCHAR(1000)
) RETURNS TABLE (
    create_day nvarchar(20), 
    schema_name nvarchar(255),
    view_name nvarchar(255)
)as
begin
  tv= select dayname(create_time) as create_day, schema_name, view_name 
  from VIEWS;
  res=APPLY_FILTER(:tv, :SQL_FILTER);
  return select * from :res;
end;
```

From the application, you can simply and safely call it by passing a parameter to a prepared statement:

```
select * from DYN_FILTER_VIEWS('view_name like ''%ELT%'' ')
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to relate to the OPs question about input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but for hana 2.0 SPS04:
I think your syntax is incorrect, you need following syntax for more than one input parameter: 

    `-- option 1 - no WITH PARAMETERS clause 
    SELECT   "FOO" 
    FROM "_SYS_BIC"."public.FOO_CV"(
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP2$$','1'),
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP1$$','2'),
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$CE_SUPPORT$$','d_calcengine'));
    --  option 2 - WITH PARAMETERS clause 
    SELECT   "FOO" 
    FROM "_SYS_BIC"."public.FOO_CV" WITH PARAMETERS (
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP2$$','1'),
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP1$$','2'),
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$CE_SUPPORT$$','d_calcengine'));
    -- option 3 - mixed 
    SELECT "FOO" 
    FROM "_SYS_BIC"."public.FOO_CV" WITH PARAMETERS (
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP2$$','1'),
    'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP1$$','2'))
    WITH PARAMETERS ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$CE_SUPPORT$$','d_calcengine'));`

The syntax you used is valid for answering an input parameter which allows for more than one value as an answer.

here, the IP1 and IP2 were created in a calculation view, whereas CE_SUPPORT input parameter is a little bit different - it can be specified for any calculation view (with or without WITH PARAMETERS clause) and is not a part of a definition of a CV.

Regarding the difference between WHERE clause and a PLACEHOLDER syntax, the differences are following:

1. the syntax is different (dough)
2. those are two different things - WHERE is used for WHERE clause and PLACEHOLDER is used for passing input parameter answer (dough)
3. point 2. makes sense only if you know what are input parameters - those are objects that can be used in variety of ways in sap hana. They can give you exact same result as a WHERE clause, but can also be used in other ways like in things called calculated columns, in mapping of input parameters, derived columns i think as well, currency conversion, etc. etc.