# HANA query with dynamic placeholder executed using jdbcTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, sql-injection, jdbctemplate, hana

I have a few HANA queries that rely on `PLACEHOLDER` input. The input to this is currently hardcoded which is leading to SQL injection vulnerability being detected by Veracode.

In order to fix that, I am trying to parameterize the value given to `PLACEHOLDER` using `PreparedStatement`, but getting the below error :

```
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM some_table (PLACEHOLDER.\"$$<IP_SOME_COLUMN>$$\" => ?) WHERE some_flag = ?; ]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [2048]; SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [34023] Instantiation of calculation model failed;exception 306002: An internal error occurred\n; nested exception is com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [34023] Instantiation of calculation model failed;exception 306002: An internal error occurred
```

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483948/how-to-escape-sql-injection-from-hana-placeholder) solution and gone through the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/52715f71adba4aaeb480d946c742d1f6/2.0.04/en-US/d5c8230abb571014acc592c2c96d92bd.html) for input parameters in SAP HANA. Below is my code :

```java
String sqlQuery = SELECT * FROM some_table ( PLACEHOLDER.\"$$<IP_SOME_COLUMN>$$\" => ? ) WHERE some_flag = ? ;

PreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter = (PreparedStatement ps) -> {
    ps.setString(1, firstInput);
    ps.setString(2, secondInput);
}

ResultSetExtractor<T> rse = new DataResultSetExtractor();

getJdbcTemplate().query(sqlQuery, preparedStatementSetter, rse);
```

The same works well with the hardcoded way (prone to SQL injection) :

```java
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
sql.append("SELECT * FROM some_table ").append("( 'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_SOME_COLUMN$$',").append(firstColumnValue).append("))");
//Map<String,Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
//getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(sql.toString(), paramMap, rse);
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the issue out. It seems, in the new syntax you need to provide the input parameter in single quotes and not in triple single quotes

Works : `'foo'`

Doesn't work : `'''bar'''`